# Changing R version in VS Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use VSCode after having used RStudio for a long time. In R Studio it is easy to change to a previous version but I cannot figure out how to change the version of R being used in VSCode.

Comment: Does this mean you have multiple versions of R installed?

Comment: Yes, it's quite easy to change between them in RStudio but no idea in VSCode

Comment: It's not a particularly nice solution but you can change the `r.rterm` and `r.rpath` settings to point to whichever version you want to run. Or turn the setting `R: Always Use Active Terminal` on and start the version you want to run from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the language settings by clicking the language in the lower right hand corner of the window:

[image]

This will open language options in the command palette:

[image]

If you click "Configure 'R' language based settings...", settings.json will open. There should be a parameter already included called "r.rterm.windows". You can update this to point to the version of R you want to use. The next time you open a new terminal, it should use this setting.

[image]